# Can I convert a dom node into a react component without loosing reference to the node?

Tags: reactjs

I have one case where one of my child components display an image. The source is passed through `props` all the way down.
However: My parent component needs a reference to the dom node of the image (or its corresponding Image Object). Wouldnt it be easier, to create the Image (as object) and passing this down to the corresponding component? If so: How do I convert a DomNode/ImageObject to a react component **and that** without making the reference in the parent node useless?

I can imagine that this is considered bad practice or not even possible. However: I wanna give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access to the ref of a child by passing a function:

```js
class Parent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ChildContainingImage imageRef={ (image) => this.image = image } />
    )
  }
}

class ChildContainingImage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <img ref={ this.props.imageRef } />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: That would indeed simplify the ref chain down to the image. However I was asking about passing a Dom node down which is then rendered by the image component

Comment: You don't interact with actual DOM nodes when working with React. I think what you are asking is not possible, because when you build your UI in the `render` function, you don't create any DOM element. You build a **representation** of the DOM using JSX. This is React which make the relation between the actual DOM and the virtual one.

Comment: I was hoping that you maybe could create a `new Image()` and passing it. This way I could keep track of the loading and the image itself.